# Delete multiple rows without knowing the names of the rows

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I have a huge database that contains writer names.

There are multiple records in my database but I don't know which rows are duplicate.

How can I delete duplicate rows without knowing the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
delete from tbl
 where writer_id in
       (select writer_id
          from (select * from tbl) t
         where exists (select 1
                  from (select * from tbl) x
                 where x.writer_name = t.writer_name
                   and t.writer_id < x.writer_id));
```

See demo:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/845ca3/1/0

This keeps the first row for each `writer_name`, in order of `writer_id` ascending.

The EXISTS subquery will run for every row, however. You could also try:

```
delete t
from
   tbl t
left join ( select writer_name, min(writer_id) as writer_id
            from tbl
            group by writer_name ) x
                                     on t .writer_name = x.writer_name
                                    and x.writer_id = t .writer_id
where
   x.writer_name is null;
```

demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/075f9/1/0

If there are no foreign key constraints on the table you could also use `create table as select` to create a new table without the duplicate entries, drop the old table, and rename the new table to that of the old table's name, getting what you want in the end. (This would not be the way to go if this table has foreign keys though)

That would look like this:

```
create table tbl2 as (select distinct writer_name from tbl);

drop table tbl;

alter table tbl2 add column writer_id int not null auto_increment first,
add primary key (writer_id);

rename table tbl2 to tbl;
```

demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8886d/1/0

Comment: I am working with one table and I want to delete multiple records in a particular column (writer_name) in this table. Does it make my question clearer?

Comment: What other columns are on the table? and what determines which row to keep, of those where the writer appears again 2,3,4... times?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/hjtxNyo.png See, Franz Kafka exists twice. I want to delete the second(or third, fourth, depend on the situation) values.

Comment: @salep see my edit, should work if you want to keep each writer_name with the lowest writer_id in situations where the same name has 2+ IDs

Comment: Update : It works well with small tables, but I can't make it work with a big table that has 50,000+ rows. It takes forever to run the query. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: The last one works perfectly. Thank you for your continuous help. I chose your answer as accepted answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.*
FROM the_table a
INNER JOIN the_table b ON a.field1 = b.field1 AND (etc)
WHERE a.pk != b.pk
```

hope that query can solve your problem.

Comment: I can't make it work. I want to delete rows that contain the same value. Could you edit your answer if it's possible, please?

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE a 
FROM tbl a 
LEFT JOIN tbl b 
ON a.field1 = b.field1 (etc)
WHERE a.id < b.id
```

this must help you